# .fadeIn .fadeOut causes strange behaviour with array index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, settimeout

I have the following code to display a string from an array at a specific index. The index is incremented each time the function is called and a new string displayed:

```js
var questions = ["What is your name?","What is your favourite colour?","What is the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow?"];
var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

function showQuestion() {
    
    if (currentQuestionIndex <= questions.length-1) {
        
        var question = $('#question');
            console.log(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
            question.text(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
        
        currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;

        questionTimer();
    } else {
        console.log("End question 1");
    }
}

function questionTimer() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        showQuestion();
    }, 3000);
}

showQuestion();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question"></div>
```

This works fine but as soon as I try to fade out / fade in the question div, the code no longer works correctly and the string at index 1 is displayed instead of 0. Could anyone explain why?

Non-working version:

```js
var questions = ["What is your name?","What is your favourite colour?","What is the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow?"];
var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

function showQuestion() {
    
    if (currentQuestionIndex <= questions.length-1) {
        
        var question = $('#question');
        question.fadeOut(400, function () {
            question.text(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
            question.fadeIn(400);
        });
        
        currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;

        questionTimer();
    } else {
        console.log("End question 1");
    }
}

function questionTimer() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        showQuestion();
    }, 3000);
}

showQuestion();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="question"></div>
```

Comment: Move `currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1; questionTimer();` in the fadeOut callback ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing +1 when the text is not yet faded out. To solve that, move everything inside the `fadeOut()` callback:

```js
var questions = ["Question 1","Question 2","Question 3","Question 4"];
var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

function showQuestion() {
    
    if (currentQuestionIndex <= questions.length-1) {
        
        var question = $('#question');
        question.fadeOut(400, function () {
            question.text(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
            question.fadeIn(400);
            currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;
            questionTimer();
        });
    } else {
        console.log("End question 1");
    }
}

function questionTimer() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        showQuestion();
    }, 3000);
}

showQuestion();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="question"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the animation is asynchronous. The code that increases the variable will run before the code that sets the text.

Increase the variable in the code that sets the text instead:

```
var question = $('#question');
question.fadeOut(400, function () {
    question.text(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
    currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;
    question.fadeIn(400);
});
```

Demo:

```js
    var questions = ["What is your name?","What is your favourite colour?","What is the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow?"];
    var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

    function showQuestion() {
        
        if (currentQuestionIndex <= questions.length-1) {
            
            var question = $('#question');
            question.fadeOut(400, function () {
                question.text(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
                currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;
                question.fadeIn(400);
            });

            questionTimer();
        } else {
            console.log("End question 1");
        }
    }

    function questionTimer() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            showQuestion();
        }, 3000);
    }

    showQuestion();
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="question"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assuming that the thread will stop execution and wait until the effects are done to continue to the next sentence. That is incorrect. The effects are run asynchronously, so while it was fading in, you were increasing the counter, so when it was ready to fade out the counter was already increased by 1.

The same way you waited until the fadeOut was done to do the fadeIn, you have to wait until the fadeIn is done to increase the value of the counter.

Easy fix

```js
var questions = ["Question 1","Question 2","Question 3","Question 4"];
var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

function showQuestion() {
    
    if (currentQuestionIndex <= questions.length-1) {
        
        var question = $('#question');
        question.fadeOut(400, function () {
            question.text(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
            question.fadeIn(400,  function() {
              currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;                       
              questionTimer();});
        });

       //move these two inside the callback for fadeIn
       //currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex+1;                       
       //questionTimer();
    } else {
        console.log("End question 1");
    }
}

function questionTimer() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        showQuestion();
    }, 3000);
}

showQuestion();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="question"></div>
```